# Use of timing system to change input variable in a function

Tags: functions, infinite-loop

Assume you have some function which is defined by a while loop:

```
sampleFunc[start_] := Module[{i},
     While[i = 1; start < 10, i++];]
```

And let's assume I do:

```
sampleFunc[5]
```

This will clearly generate an infinite loop. Thus, for my purposes, say I would like then to increase the starting value by 1 whenever the time taken for `sampleFunc` exceeds 2 seconds. I continuously do this until `sampleFunc` completes its evaluation under 2 seconds. Something like:

```
While[timeTaken[sampleFunc[s]]>2,s=s-1]
```

Things like `TimeConstrained` abort the evaluation, whereas I don't want to abort the entire program. I just want to abort the `sampleFunc` part, change the variable and then reevaluate `sampleFunc` until it's evaluation time is less than 2 sec.

I know `sampleFunc` is extremely simplistic and usless, but it serves the purpose I need in order to apply it to a much more complex function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo[n_] := If[n < 10, While[True], "done"] (*instead of your sampleFunc*)
```

You don't need to abort, there is a third argument for `TimeConstrained`:

```
n = 1;
While[TimeConstrained[res = foo[n], .5, True], Echo[n++]]
res
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I had looked at the extra arguments for TimeConstrained. I guess I didn't understand it correctly. But thanks, it's just how I needed it.